# Javascript Pouch DB doesn't load on Safari & Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, safari, pouchdb

We have built a small script and a database, based on PouchDB in order to display all the products of one of our clients in a so called "product tree".
You can find the product tree here: http://www.bodyrevitaliser.nl/nl/service/product-tree/

As you can see the tree is loading properly only in Chrome. If you check the console in safari and Firefox the DB seems to be loaded as well but something seems to be blocking the tree itself to be loaded.

What are you thoughts? Any ideas what might be causing this and solutions.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that your usage of promises is not correct. I *strongly* recommend you read this blog post: [We have a problem with promises](http://pouchdb.com/2015/05/18/we-have-a-problem-with-promises.html). I know it's long, but it's worthwhile to read the whole thing.

In particular, read the section called "WTF, how do I use forEach() with promises?", because that is exactly the mistake that you're making. You are doing a bunch of insertions inside of a `$.each`, and then you are immeditely doing an `allDocs()` inside the same function. So you have zero guarantees that any documents have actually been inserted into PouchDB by the time you try to read from PouchDB. Perhaps it will, perhaps it won't, but it all depends on subtle timing differences between different browsers, so you can't count on it.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation @nlawson. I will share this with the specific person who wrote the code and will take a detailed look at the article in order to understand the problem. Will let you know if the problem was solved.

Comment: we implemented what you suggested, but it still doesn't seem to solve the issue. One if the interesting things is that on some devices it works on safari, on some not and on firefox it only works when its not within the iframe. Would be great if u can take another look and advise us how to proceed. Maybe embedding the iframe is not the best way in this case.

Comment: IndexedDB and iframes generally do not mix. I don't remember the details, but I think Firefox will definitely block IDB access unless the iframe and outside frame are at the same origin.

Comment: Ok, great. We will look for another way to implement it and let you know if it worked. Thanks for the answer.